# Setting up relation using existing navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have sql query similar to:

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM table1 as t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.someid1= t2.id
 LEFT JOIN table3 t3 on t1.someid2 = t3.id and t2.id2 = t3.id2
```

I'm trying to setup navigation properties for these tables. With table 2 it is simple:

```
t1Entity
 .HasOne(t1=>t.t2)
 .WithMany()
 .HasForeignKey(t1=>t1.someid1)
 .HasPrincipalKey(t2=>t2.id);
```

How do I setup navigation property for table 3?
When I try to do this, I get following error:

```
t1Entity
     .HasOne(t1=>t.t3)
     .WithMany()
     .HasForeignKey(t1=> new{t1.someid2, t1.t2.id2})
     .HasPrincipalKey(t3 =>new{t3.id, t3.id2});
```

> The properties expression 'e => new <>...' is not valid. The
> expression should represent a simple property access: 't =>
> t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous
> type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'

Comment: Looks like this one is not correct `t1.t2.id2`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I understand that. How do I accomplish the same result as in query?

Comment: Navigation property is relation to ONE another table. Exception is Many-To-Many relation which requires intermediate table. And how query is related to Database design?